# Ошибка setImageBitmap, выдает OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Prtoject on [GitHub](https://github.com/MediaPortal1/HowToDraw/tree/master/app/src/main).

В общем жил да был у меня метод `img.setImageResources(R.id.image)`, но что-то часто он вызывал ошибку OutOfMemory. При частом вызывании этого метода, при повороте экрана. Потом в [документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) гугла нашел статью о том как "правильно" грузить битмапы в активити.
Скопировал себе 2 последних метода из этой статьи и вот что вышло:

```
   Handler handler=new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(getRequestedOrientation()==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,100,100));
                else imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,400,400));
            }
        };
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(image);
```

Да, я даже решил это в отдельном потоке вызывать. Оказалось что так работает куда быстрее(раза в 2). Как видите я присваиваю картинке битмап ещё в зависимости от ориентации. Так как в лэнд-ориентации картиночка по меньше и что бы лишние пиксили не грузились. Вроде бы вся эта конструкция чудно работала ещё сегодня утром. Не трогал этот экран вообще, но вот почему андроид вредный решил что не хочет что-бы все это хорошо работало. Поработал немного над этим приложением(просто картинки в проект добавлял свои). Перекомпилил пару-тройку раз и теперь не просто вылазит ошибка "Время от времени", а каждый раз при запуске активити. То есть программа теперь постоянно вылетает. С той же самой любимой OutOfMemory. 
Как так? Что делать?

Код ошибки:

```
Process: com.poltavets.app.howtodraw, PID: 28720                                                                  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 35389452 byte allocation with 5482128 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:655)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:488)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:511)
at com.poltavets.app.howtodraw.view.HowTo.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(HowTo.java:224)
at com.poltavets.app.howtodraw.view.HowTo$3.handleMessage(HowTo.java:185)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Код метода который меняет картинку:

```
public void changeImageSrc(int image,int count,int position,String name) {
        filename=name+"_"+image+"_"+position;
        imagenumber=position;
        if(move!=null || back!=null) {
            move.setEnabled(false);
            back.setEnabled(false);
        }
        Handler handler=new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(getRequestedOrientation()==ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,100,100));
                else imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), msg.what,400,400));
            }
        };
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(image);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_how_to) + " " + name + ": " + (position+1)+"/"+(count));
            if(position==0 || position+1==count){
                if(position==0){
                    findViewById(R.id.backBtn).setEnabled(false);
                    findViewById(R.id.backBtn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    findViewById(R.id.moveBtn).setEnabled(false);
                    findViewById(R.id.moveBtn).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.finish),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                showNavButtons();
            }
        if(move!=null || back!=null) {
            move.setEnabled(true);
            back.setEnabled(true);
        }

        }
```

А вот 2 метода из документации гугла которые я всунул в код:

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

А вот и пример картинки что-бы вы поверили что она весит не 30мб(эта весит 200кб, но ошибку вызывает такая же только 80кб):
[image: Картинка которая вызывает OutOfMemory]

Comment: судя по стактрейсу, у вас какая-то большая картинка, размером 35 389 452 байт (больше 35 мегабайт.)   Покажите все-таки ваш метод `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource`, и строку HowTo.java:224

Comment: Этод метод по ссылке есть 1 в 1. Ничего не менял. Картинка весит 80кб. Строка 224:         return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

Comment: Покажите полностью код. Что-то не верится что картинка в весом 80кб OutOfMemory вызывает

Comment: Может там упакованное изображение 6000х6000 в котором все пиксели одного цвета ?

Comment: Добавил и код и картинку.

Comment: Еще и ссылку на Гитхаб добавил.